# Update statement within select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, with-statement, case-when

I am trying to write a query in which I update a counter based on other conditions. For example:

```
with table 1 as (select *, count from table1)

select box_type, 
case when box_type = lag(box_type) over (order by time) 
then 
  count, update table1 set count = count + 1
else
  count
end as identifier
```

Here's the basic jist of what I'm trying to do. I want a table that looks like this:

| box_type | identifier |
| --- | --- |
| small | 1 |
| small | 1 |
| small | 1 |
| medium | 2 |
| medium | 2 |
| large | 3 |
| large | 3 |
| small | 4 |

I just want to increment that identifier value every time the box_type changes

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question only makes sense if you have a column that sepcifies the ordering.  Let me assume such a column exists -- based on your code, I'll call it `time`.

Then, you can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t1.*,
       count(*) filter (where box_type is distinct from prev_box_type) over (order by time) as count
from (select t1.*,
             lag(box_type) over (order by time) as prev_box_type
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I'm now trying to put this into Snowflake. Do you know how to convert this function to the appropriate syntax?

Comment: @Brad . . . I just answered the follow-on question for this.